# Initiating Phone Call in Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova, tel

I am able to use "tel:" hyperlinks to invoke the Call screen.But, I want to iniate the call also  subsequently  for configured number.

Is there any way to do this in phonegap for android. ?

Comment: When I  click, Call should be Invoked

Comment: No.  For obvious security reasons you cannot start a phone call.  It *must* have user intervention or there would be a ton of apps out there that dial premium services in your sleep and cost you a fortune.